# IF statement and && operator considering BinaryTreeSearch

Tags: java, if-statement, operator-keyword

im coding in java
Plz help me to understand why the && operator doesnt work in this statment, thx alot

```
    public boolean isLeaf(BinarySearchTree<T> tree) {
    if(tree.right && tree.left = null)return true;

            else 
    return false;
```

greetz blubber

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
if(tree.right==null && tree.left==null) return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please explain what you want to do exactly ?

to compare you have to use "==" not "="

"=" is to assign values

to assign a value you do something like x = 1
and to compare you do something like if (x==1) not if (x=1)

To get back to your code, I think you wanted something like:

```
if( (tree.right && tree.left) == null)return true;
```

(you can remove the additionnal () that i added, they are just to clarify reading)

Comment: you are welcome :)...a +1 would be appreciated ;)
plz tag your question as resolved